# Syntax for "and" and distinct operation in entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to display the records whose accountid, id are matching and also display distinct records.

```
var result = from a in cxt.tblInventoryProducts
             where a.aid == accID && a.id == id
             select new
             {
                 a.productType,
                 a.productName
             };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var result = from a in cxt.tblInventoryProducts
             where a.aid == accID && a.id == id
             group a by new { a.productType, a.productName } into grp
             select new
             {
                 grp.Key.productType,
                 grp.Key.productName
             };
```